# Checking for a custom ActiveX plugin in Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

I am developing a web application that installs plugins and checks other requirements for a larger web application I have built.  I am having problems, however, with checking for a custom ActiveX control.  I can check for it by trying to instantiate it with an `<OBJECT>` tag, but then it tries to install the plugin if the user is missing it, when I just need a javascript boolean returned whether or not the control is already installed.  I have been searching around for a simple solution to this, but I can't quite find anything that works.  Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Check the HTML at get.adobe.com/flashplayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say:

```
try {
    new ActiveXObject(...);
} catch {
    // Not installed. 
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I'm not sure what name to use in the `new ActiveXObject()` function if it's a custom cab file.  Do I just use the cab file name?

Comment: You use the guid.  If you want to use a string, you have to register (and then use) an APPID for your object.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688754(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok, I have been using the CLSID, and still cannot make the object.  Can you show me an example of this chunk of code with a CLSID?  Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Okay, I can't find an example.  And I was wrong about the APPID.  You want to register a PROGID.  Sorry, my COM has gotten rusty.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2006/01/10/511279.aspx?Redirected=true